# Cocoa PDFView only displays PDF on resize

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, pdf, pdfkit

How does one get a PDFView to display a PDF without having to resize the window or doing a
scroll to force a redraw.

It's as if a `setNeedsDisplay` needs to be done, yet that has no effect.

I've the simplest app I can think of to display a PDF using a PDFView.

Basically create a new app in Xcode and change the code to be:

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet PDFView *pdfView;
@end
```

and

```
// AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize pdfView = _pdfView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TestPage" withExtension:@"pdf"];
    PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL: pdfURL];     
    self.pdfView.document = document;
}
@end
```

I've noticed the same behaviour in the Apple code example [PDFKitLinker2](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PDFKitLinker2/Introduction/Intro.html) where one has to either scroll over the PDF or resize the window to get the PDF to display.

Granted I'm new to the world of Cocoa development but I've searched and found no really small examples that show how to display a PDF. What I've produced would seem to be correct yet I have doubts given that even **PDFKitLinker2** doesn't seem to be correct.

I've created a Git repo of an [Xcode project that demonstrates the issue](https://bitbucket.org/sotapme/pdfview_open) for those that have time to help and/or comment.

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:sotapme/pdfview_open.git
```

Using Xcode Version 4.3.3 (4E3002) - Latest Lion.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

### A Solution that works.

---

I found a solution whereby if I create a sub class of PDFView with an empty implementation and then add that as a custom view and wire it up my existing `IBOutlet` it works.

Makes no sense at all to me :(

```
//DPPDFView.h
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
@interface DPPDFView : PDFView
@end
```

and

```
//DPPDFView.m
#import "DPPDFView.h"
@implementation DPPDFView
@end
```

Apple's docs do say:

> PDFView may be the only class you need to deal with for adding PDF functionality to your application. It lets you display PDF data and allows users to select content, navigate through a document, set zoom level, and copy textual content to the Pasteboard. PDFView also keeps track of page history.
>
> You can subclass PDFView to create a custom PDF viewer.

*I leave this question and self answer for those that may pass by with similar questions, hoping that it will be a dim beacon of light for them; Also hoping someone with more Cocoa wisdom will point out the error in my thinking.*

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you - the first page of a PDFView is blank until you scroll or resize, at which point it redraws, and continues to work fine from there.  But your solution of subclassing PDFView doesn't fix it for me.  Hmm.

Comment: @stevex, have you tried pulling my example code to see if it then works for you ? git clone git@bitbucket.org:sotapme/pdfview_open.git

Comment: I contacted Apple about this, and it ended up being a bug in 10.7.4, that's fixed in 10.8.  The workaround is to resize the view, and a short time later (ie, in a dispatch_async block on the main queue), size the view back.

Comment: That's a good spot @stevex, thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that the bug does not occur under 10.8.5; the empty sub class (or resize + resize) workarounds are no longer needed.

Comment: It seems this bug has returned in 10.11 (and 10.11.1). That or something similar, though it happens every time I call goToPage: now, not just on initial load. Anyone else found this as well?

Comment: @c-had are you able to fix this issue @10.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this is indeed caused by the PDFview needing a setNeedsDisplay *after* lazyloading has finished actually loading the PDF document.

A hack, but adding the below to your - (void)windowDidLoad method at least displays the document properly without needing a resize.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.myPDFView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
});
```

Comment: Thanks that should help @Wouter.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the "Wants Core Animation" flag in the view results in some wonky behaviour.  If you have that set, try adding:

```
[pdfView setLayerContentsRedrawPolicy: NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay];
[pdfView setNeedsDisplay: YES];
```

to your function that loads the PDFView.

Comment: _interestingly_ enough, using my original 'bad-code' I looked into what you said and my "Core Animation Layer" for the PDFView was un-ticked, so I ticked it and it started to work ! Then I tried to mak e it the smallest change possible. Then I found out the bad news that it only works occasionally even callying the built App directly from the finder, sometimes when it runs it does display the PDF and other times it doesn't. Even adding your code made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's an hypothesis, but it might be because when you `self.pdfView.document = document;` the PDFView out of the NIB hasn't been instantiated !

Obj-C doesn't shout at you when you pass messages to the `nil` object.

To test this hypothesis, you can `NSLog()` your `pdfView` to see if it is `nil`.